# S7.NET isConnected return value why always true after a succesful connect even if I disconnect the cable?

Tags: c#, wpf, plc, siemens

I connected my PC to a Siemens PLC with S7.NET library in a C# WPF app. There is a property, isConnected. If I connect to the PLC with plc.Open() the property return value becomes true. But, If I disconnect the PLC cable, the property value still true. Why?

```
 private void checkPlcConnection()
    {
        Plc plc = new Plc(CpuType.S71200, "192.168.0.1", 0, 1);
        plc.Open(); // Cable was connected when method called

        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Trace.WriteLine(plc.IsConnected); // True, after remove the cable still true
        }
    }
```

Comment: See the code below

Comment: Please don't post code as picture, [related topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1997232).

Answer (score 2):

I googled (actually duckduckgoed) *s7.net "isconnected"* and found this document:

http://www.ad.siemens.com.cn/club/bbs/upload/file/20181129/6367911382823920496914596.pdf

I would recommend you use the method `IsAvailable` instead of `IsConnected`.  It actively determines if you are still connected by ping-ing.

Actually, you probably need to do both, `IsConnected && IsAvailable`